# VB silverlight for windows phone "system.xml.linq.xelement"

Tags: vb.net, silverlight, windows-phone-7

Hello i am having this problem:
i am downloading data from xml using linq library 
those data i want to add them on a textblock item

```
TextBlock1.Text = TextBlock1.Text & result
```

but it has an error :

> Error 1   Operator '&' is not defined for types 'String' and 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement'.

When i am changing this line to :

```
TextBlock1.Text = TextBlock1.Text & result.Tostring
```

it works but it adds this data :

```
"<"data> data <"/data>
```

instead of :

```
hello
```

any ideas ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want `result.Value`:

```
TextBlock1.Text = TextBlock1.Text & result.Value
```

You can look at the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.value.aspx) for more information about `XElement.Value`.

On another note, you can use:

```
TextBlock1.Text &= result.Value
```

As a shorter way of writing it.

Comment: @DimitrisSapikas Excellent, glad to hear.